# how do i switch database user if one user has to many attempts

Tags: php, mysql

I have this database class

```
 function MySQLDB(){
  /* Make connection to database */
  $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
  /**
   * Only query database to find out number of members
   * when getNumMembers() is called for the first time,
   * until then, default value set.
   */
  $this->num_members = -1;

  if(TRACK_VISITORS){
     /* Calculate number of users at site */
     $this->calcNumActiveUsers();

     /* Calculate number of guests at site */
     $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
  }


}
```

and I am getting max_user_connections error with only 12 users logged in.  I saw this script that shows to toggle between user to connect if user exceeds quota.

```
 ini_set('display_errors', '0');
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if (mysql_errno() == 1040 OR mysql_errno() == 1203) {
    define("DB_HOST", "some_ip:3306");//remote
    define("DB_NAME", "db");  //database_name
    define("DB_USER", "user"); //database user name
    define("DB_PASSWORD","pass");  //database (user) password
}
else
{
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_NAME", "db_name2");  //database_name
    define("DB_USER", "user"); //database user name
    define("DB_PASSWORD","pass");  //database (user) password
}
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//by feha at www.vision.to
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to put this feature in my class.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Will this work and reset $this->connection to a secondary user if there is a error?

```
function MySQLDB(){
  /* Make connection to database */
  $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
  if (mysql_errno() == 1040 OR mysql_errno() == 1203) {
  $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SEC_USER, DB_SEC_PASS) or die(mysql_error());    
  }
  mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
  /**
   * Only query database to find out number of members
   * when getNumMembers() is called for the first time,
   * until then, default value set.
   */
  $this->num_members = -1;

  if(TRACK_VISITORS){
     /* Calculate number of users at site */
     $this->calcNumActiveUsers();

     /* Calculate number of guests at site */
     $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
  }
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183727/how-to-solve-mysql-max-user-connections-error

Comment: that is what i am referring to, but would like to know how i can incorporate into my class.

Comment: BTW, I'm guessing you never call `mysql_close`, or often exit or redirect before the call to it.

Comment: also my host only allows me 10 connections per user and does not allow me to update.  I'm trying to switch user if the script gets the error

Comment: "my host only allows me 10 connections per user" Look for new hosting. That's the only real solution.  That's an absurd restriction, unless its free hosting.

Comment: right developerwjk.  its a dumb restriction... its ipower

Comment: I'd suggest nothing but change your hosting provider, limitations on sQL like that is not worth the time

Comment: I just update the original question with a possible solution... can you tell me if this will work?

Comment: also anyone have recommendation for good host with high max_user_connections