# Getting 'max_user_connections' active connections in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting below error in codeigniter. I have checked different servers.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (42000/1203): User searcgav_search
>   already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 201
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/searcgav/public_html/v1/application/controllers/Index.php
>   Line: 13 Function: __construct
>
> File: /home/searcgav/public_html/v1/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: controllers/Index.php
>
> Line Number: 13

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183727/how-to-solve-mysql-max-user-connections-error

Comment: check this in your error **Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.**