# SpringBoot MySQL JDBC Unable to create initial connections of pool

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, spring-boot

Good day!

I have a simple springboot application with mysql jdbc repository.

I have properties for connect to DB

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://*:3306/*?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=*
spring.datasource.password=*
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=1
```

My test DB has only max 10 connections for user. When I use console

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'threads_connected';
```

I can see that now DB has 5 connections only but when I try to start my application I get Exception

> 2018-02-28 10:26:24.115 ERROR 17360 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
>   o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial
>   connections of pool.
>
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: User '*' has exceeded the
>   'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)

How can I fix it? And why I get that Exception if I have 5 free connetion on DB and I need only 1 connection for pool from properties? I can't edit max connection on DB because use Heroku like testDB. I can edit only tomcat properties only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve MySQL max\_user\_connections error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183727/how-to-solve-mysql-max-user-connections-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You configured the following property:

```
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=1
```

This indicates that you're trying to use the [DBCP 2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) connection pool. However, when you check the stacktrace, you can see the following:

```
o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
```

As the package of the `ConnectionPool` class is `org.apache.tomcat`, this indicates that you're actually using the default Tomcat connection pool. This means that your `max-total` poperty is not being picked up properly.

If you want to configure this for a Tomcat connection pool, you need to use the `maxActive` property:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the Tomcat connection pool, you can add the DBCP 2 dependency using Maven/Gradle/... . If you exclude the default Tomcat connection pool, it will automatically pick up DBCP 2.

Another possibility is to configure it by using the `spring.datasource.type` property as mentioned by [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database):

> You can bypass that algorithm completely and specify the connection pool to use via the `spring.datasource.type` property. This is especially important if you are running your application in a Tomcat container as tomcat-jdbc is provided by default.

For example:

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
```

Comment: Greate! It is answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in similar situation but the simple fix for this could be like the database that you are pointing in `application.properties` probably does not exist.

Or You can try to delete org.springframework.data folder from `C:\Users\{yourusername}\.m2` folder and update Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly same error and It worked for me after changing the spring boot version from 1.5.* to 2.1.8.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here... try to change the version on parent like says SaravanaKumar but the project is to old and I get a lot of deprecated.

I Fixed by change only the database version

> ```
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>       <version>8.0.23</version> <!--Add that Line-->
>       <scope>runtime</scope>
>   </dependency>
> ```

Note: if update on parent all dependency get update.